# web scraping with python beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the html code

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
"{"Title":"One Indian Girl","Year":"2016","Author":"Chetan Bhagat"}"
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to scrap things i need.Like i only need the **Author name** from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip tags and convert json string to python dict:

```
import json
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
text = soup.get_text().strip().strip('"')
d = json.loads(text)
print(d['Author'])
```

Answer (score 0):

**@vijay**, `print json.loads(soup.find("pre").string[2:-2])["Author"];` will do the job. Please have a look at the below code executed on Python interactive terminal.

```
>>> import json
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> html_text = """<html>
... <head></head>
... <body>
... <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
... "{"Title":"One Indian Girl","Year":"2016","Author":"Chetan Bhagat"}"
... </pre>
... </body>
... </html>"""
>>>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
>>> print(soup.prettify())
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
"{"Title":"One Indian Girl","Year":"2016","Author":"Chetan Bhagat"}"
</pre>
 </body>
</html>
>>>
>>> print(soup.find("pre"))
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
"{"Title":"One Indian Girl","Year":"2016","Author":"Chetan Bhagat"}"
</pre>
>>>
>>> print(soup.find("pre").string)

"{"Title":"One Indian Girl","Year":"2016","Author":"Chetan Bhagat"}"

>>> print(soup.find("pre").string[2:-2])
{"Title":"One Indian Girl","Year":"2016","Author":"Chetan Bhagat"}
>>>
>>> d = json.loads(soup.find("pre").string[2:-2])
>>> type(d)
<type 'dict'>
>>>
>>> d
{u'Author': u'Chetan Bhagat', u'Year': u'2016', u'Title': u'One Indian Girl'}
>>>
>>> d["Author"]
u'Chetan Bhagat'
>>>
>>> d["Year"]
u'2016'
>>>
>>> d["Title"]
u'One Indian Girl'
>>>
>>> # Place all in the list
...
>>> l = [d["Title"], d["Year"], d["Author"]]
>>> l
[u'One Indian Girl', u'2016', u'Chetan Bhagat']
>>>
```

» Getting data inside a list without referring keys of dictionary as above.

```
>>> final_data = [str(a.strip().split(":")[1])  for  a in soup.find("pre").string[2:-3].replace('\"', '').split(",")]
>>>
>>> final_data
['One Indian Girl', '2016', 'Chetan Bhagat']
>>>
```

Let's undserstand the above direct procedure to get data inside a list step by step (updated).

```
>>> data = soup.find("pre").string[2:-3]
>>> data
u'{"Title":"One Indian Girl","Year":"2016","Author":"Chetan Bhagat"'
>>>
>>> data = data.replace('\"', '')
>>> data
u'{Title:One Indian Girl,Year:2016,Author:Chetan Bhagat'
>>>
>>> arr = data.split(",")
>>> arr
[u'{Title:One Indian Girl', u'Year:2016', u'Author:Chetan Bhagat']
>>>
>>> final_data = [str(a.strip().split(":")[1])  for  a in arr]
>>> final_data
['One Indian Girl', '2016', 'Chetan Bhagat']
>>>
```

Comment: What if i need to get all answers in a python list. Like [One Indian Girl,2016,Chetan Bhagat] . Only the answers not the headings.@Rishikesh Agrawani

Comment: **@vijay**, Just use `l = [d["Title"], d["Year"], d["Author"]]`. I've updated the answer. See at the end.

Comment: I don't want to mention the name of the heading.i have similar html page with more than 50 headings.so i don't want to mention each heading. so is there any other way @Rishikesh Agrawani?

Comment: **@vijay**, can you please explain me, what is heading? Please paste the example so that I could understand.

Comment: sorry.Heading is key in the dictionary.Like "Title" in "Title":"One Indian Girl".Likewise all others.I have more than 50 key value pairs. @Rishikesh Agrawani

Comment: **@vijay**, just use `final_data = [str(a.strip().split(":")[1])  for  a in soup.find("pre").string[2:-3].replace('\"', '').split(",")]`. finally you can use a loop for processing 50 html pages. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. @Rishikesh Agrawani

Comment: No problem **@vijay**.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i was looking for.

```
exampleSoup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
text = exampleSoup.get_text().strip().strip('"')
elems=json.loads(text)  
Details=list(elems.values())
for i in Details:
    print(i)
```

**elems** gives us dictionary.

I have taken the values from the key-value pairs of the dictionary as **Details**.

**For loop** is used to get each element separately.